# Using paw-server library in my android app

Tags: android

I want to use Paw Server's Android library (`paw-server.jar`). Is it legal to use this library in my Android app ? I am so confused about copyrights and licenses, please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is, but there are some conditions: it takes a bit of searching but there's a [license page](http://paw-project.sourceforge.net/documentation/index.html) in their documentation, which I'll reproduce here, that covers all of this. The main part is (emphasis mine):

> Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
>    modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
>    are met: [...]

So, as long as those conditions are met, you are free to use it. **Also**, the main page states that

> You can build your own server based on PAW free of charge for private and educational purposes. If you would like to build a commercial product, please contact: paw [at] fun2.code.de

So, if you intend to use it in a free app, this shouldn't be a problem but if you intend to sell it, you'll need to contact the developer.

Comment: And I contacted all the email  in the website [link] (http://paw-android.fun2code.de)  still no one responded

Comment: This seems to be a small open source project, possibly a very small company: be patient, they might get back to you in a few days. Consider the possibility, too, that the project might be dead and the developer stopped working on it; in that case, you might think about forking the project but since the project in not really open sourced, I guess this falls into a kind of legal gray area...

Comment: He replied and allowed to use his library thank you SolarBear